# Excel formula matching sheet1 and sheet2 and getting result

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Can someone please help on Excel formula:
I have a spredsheet With two sheets.

1. In sheet1 I have two column
2. In sheet2 I have tree column.
3. I want two column from sheet1 to match With two column in sheet2.
4. When match get result from the column 3 in sheet2 into an cell in sheet1.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1248964/index-match-across-multiple-columns

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula and check if this will help you:

```
=LOOKUP(1,0/((Sheet2!A:A=Sheet1!A2)*(Sheet2!B:B=Sheet1!B2)),Sheet2!C:C)
```

[image]

[image]